# Powershell SendKeys No Input

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a dual pc stream setup and would like to use my elgato stream deck on my gaming pc for some specific functions.  The only problem is, no obs control.  I was combing through reddit and came across the suggestion to use SendKeys in powershell scripts to perform hotkey functions.  I am able to connect the two computers through PSSession and run my script, but nothing happens.  I have the application focused.  Even when I just open a text file and run the script, nothing comes up.  I don't really think this should be that hard should it?  Any help would be appreciated.

`$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys(']')`

Comment: Your post indicates you are not familiar with PowerShell GUI automation and the particulars of SendKeys. SendKeys is not a PowerShell-specific thing. It's been around since [VBScript has existed](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html). There are tons of blogs on SendKeys of VBScript, [PowerShell](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20using%20sendkeys&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20using%20sendkeys&sc=1-25&sk=&cvid=E09C0D2EF94E47CEB18034D44EA834F1), and tons of Youtube videos on the topic. So you can look to them for guidance as well.

Comment: While I may not be overly familiar with it, I have been going over a bunch of posts, tutorials and videos for several hours today.  I kinda decided to jump into the deep end on this one it seems.  None of the different sources I've come across so far today have really helped unfortunately.  I did get the key function to work on a local computer, but now I'm getting an error when I try to run it on a remote computer

Comment: "but now I'm getting an error when I try to run it on a remote computer" Feel free to post another question with this exact problem, if you do not find a solution for it on [so] already.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment...

Sendkeys is a thing but can be really finicky, focus, timing issues, etc.  GUI automation is not really PowerShell's strong suit. Custom tools like AutoIT, Selenium, etc., are better options.

With Sendkeys, you often must set delays to ensure focus before calling keystrokes.

YOu can also avoid the use of ...

```
New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
```

... and use this...

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

Here are a few examples you can try.

```
# pops the WinKey Start Menu
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{ESC}')
```

Or this way...

```
# Initialize a variable with the .Net namespace, then use it.
$SendKeys = [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]
$SendKeys::SendWait('^{ESC}')

# SendKeys to hold down keys
$SendKeys::SendWait('q(+%) + (+)q')

# Send commnad results to notepad - Note the sleep to wait for notepad to open, paste the content then select the file menu
Get-NetIPConfiguration | clip | notepad
Sleep -Seconds 1
$SendKeys::SendWait('^V')
Sleep -Seconds 2
$SendKeys::SendWait('%F')
```

Update as per our comments below:

***SendKeys requires a GUI up and running. A GUI requires a logged-on, interactive user.***

Comment: Well, I got it to work on a local system, but I cannot call the script on the remote computer.  I created an identical script to serve the same function to call on the remote computer, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  I keep getting an access is denied error.  With a few minutes of research it's possible that it's due to the script running with no gui

Comment: SendKeys, requires a logged-on user, because only then I the GUI available. PowerShell runs in the context of the logged-on user who launched it. You are not the interactive user, so ***you cannot do interactive/GUI stuff via a remote PowerShell session***. This is the Windows OS security boundary, that PowerShell respects. You need to consider using a scheduled task, launched in the context of the logged-on user, or as a service account, and report back to you on completion.