# Powershell Script isn't executing OBS ctrl+5 hotkey

Tags: powershell

I am using OBS which is a video recorder, and I have it set to where if I press a hot key (ctrl + 5), it snaps the last 15 seconds. I want this powershell script to simply push that hotkey and that is it! I had it working with ctrl+alt+g in a different program, but for some reason this doesn't.

I can press ctrl + 5, and it does record the snap shot/replay; however, if I run the powershell script, it does not!

This is the powershell script I tried to launch to see if it would execute the hot key, but it doesn't. It worked before with a different program, but I don't know what the issue is. I have set my Powershell to unrestricted.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{5}")
```

this is the Powershell script I launch to press Ctrl+5.

Answer (score -3):

> Edited on 01/03/2024:

Sorry for the delay. I've been looking around. Kindly check out this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138816/powershell-sendkeys-no-input) on sending a key-stroke using a script.

They offer a detailed solution to the same issue. Again, I apologize for my weak attempt at resolving your problem. Happy New Year, by the way!✨

Comment: I appreciate the help, but still having same issue. I see the powershell screen run, but the hotkeys for my video editor still don't seem to recognize it.